# Mysql Trigger insertion replacing unicode with question marks(???)

Tags: mysql, unicode, triggers

I have 2 tables `homework`  and `trigger`. When a new row gets inserted in `homework`, I triggered it to insert `homework` column text(`unicode`) in to `trigger` table. In `homework` table, unicode is proper but in `trigger` table unicode text is replacing with question marks(???)

like this:

```
Eng- ????? ????? ????? q???????????    f???? ?????? ?????. (Tamil language test)#Kan: ???? ???? ?????? ????????? ???? ?????????? ????? ??????? #ACC: ???? ???? ?????? ????????? ???? ?????????? ????? ???????
```

`trigger` table column `collation` is `utf8_unicode_ci` which is same as `homework` table column

(from Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE trigger (
    TriggerId int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    TableName varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
    Homework mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
    SchoolId int(100) NOT NULL, 
    DateTimeRecordInserted timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (TriggerId), 
    KEY TriggerId (TriggerId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1247487 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please follow this while asking your questions - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: Share the SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW CREATE TRIGGER along with your question. @bhanuchand panthala

Comment: CREATE TABLE `trigger` (
 `TriggerId` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `TableName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `Homework` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `SchoolId` int(100) NOT NULL,
 `DateTimeRecordInserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`TriggerId`),
 KEY `TriggerId` (`TriggerId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1247487 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Again, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Let's see `CREATE TABLE` for the other table and `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DECLARE var_row_data MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer if it was already in place??